# How to maintain the model and bindingResult of the controller when moving the view of ajax

Tags: java, ajax, spring, model-view-controller, controller

I tried the following. However, when moving a view by location.href, the model and bindingResult are not maintained. How to maintain the model and bindingResult? *Maybe the approach is wrong...*

#### Controller

```
    @PostMapping("/example")
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, Object> example(
            @RequestPart("formRequest") @Validated FormRequest formRequest,
            BindingResult bindingResult,
            @RequestPart(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file,
            @RequestPart(value = "files", required = false) MultipartFile[] files,
            Model model
    ) {
        Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
        
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            log.warn("bindingResult={}", bindingResult);
            model.addAttribute("formRequest", formRequest);
            model.addAttribute("formStatus", FormStatus.CREATE);
            response.put("errors", bindingResult.getAllErrors());
            
            response.put("url", "/example");
            return response;
        }

        return response;
    }
```

#### formRequest

```
public record FormRequest(
        Long id,
        @NotBlank
        String content1,
        @NotBlank
        String content2,
        @NotBlank
        String content3,
        @NotNull
        Integer number1,
        @NotNull
        Integer number2,
        @NotNull
        List<GoodRequest> goodRequests,
        @NotNull
        List<DimRequest> dimRequests,
        String category
) {}
```

#### ajax

```
        $.ajax({
          url: url,
          type: "POST",
          data: formData,
          enctype: "multipart/form-data",
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          success: function (response) {
            location.href = response.url;
          }
        });
```

Comment: When you redirect the page using `location.href` the current page is reloaded and any data stored in the model or `BindingResult` are lost

Comment: When you navigate the user to a new page, the user is navigated to a new page.  It's as though the user clicked on a link, or manually typed a new address into the browser.  Anything and everything from the previous page is lost.  Taking a step back... Why would you want to navigate the user to a new page after performing an AJAX operation anyway?  The point of AJAX is to not require navigation.  If page navigation is the goal then don't use AJAX in the first place and just let the user submit the form.  It's not really clear what the underlying goal is here.

Comment: @David Added formRequest code. If you look at the formRequest, there are List<GoodRequest>  and List<DimRequest> , and you had to collect GoodRequest and DimRequest from javascript, respectively, and send them to the controller. So I used ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you redirect the page using `location.href`, the current page is reloaded and any data stored in the model or `BindingResult` is lost. One way to maintain the data between requests is to store it in the session or pass it as URL parameters.

In your case, you could modify your controller to store the `formRequest` and `bindingResult` objects in the session, and then retrieve them from the session when rendering the view. Modify you code as follow:

```java
@PostMapping("/example")
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, Object> example(
        @RequestPart("formRequest") @Validated FormRequest formRequest,
        BindingResult bindingResult,
        @RequestPart(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file,
        @RequestPart(value = "files", required = false) MultipartFile[] files,
        Model model,
        HttpSession session
) {
    Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        log.warn("bindingResult={}", bindingResult);
        // Store formRequest and bindingResult in the session
        session.setAttribute("formRequest", formRequest);
        session.setAttribute("bindingResult", bindingResult);
        response.put("errors", bindingResult.getAllErrors());

        response.put("url", "/example");
        return response;
    }

    return response;
}
```

Then in your view, you can retrieve the `formRequest` and `bindingResult` objects from the session and use them.